# $x+y = π/2$ and $ \sin x +\cos y =1$. We should find $\sin x =$?

Tags: trigonometry

Maybe I rushed a bit and thought that the answer was $\sin x = 1$, but still after watching it closely I can not understand why this is not a possible answer.
(The correct answer in my book is $0.5$)

Comment: $y=\pi/2-x$, what is $\cos(y)$?

Comment: I just realised it. Thank you, maybe i am too tired to have not seen this!

Answer (score 2):

You have that:$$\cos y = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right) = \sin x \Rightarrow \sin x+ \sin x = 1 \Rightarrow \sin x = \dfrac{1}{2}$$